# Python Hangman game and replacing multiple occurrences of letters

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is my first year programming with Python. 
I am trying to create a hangman game.

So my questions: how do I check for

1. If the person is guessing a letter that has already been guessed and where to include it.
2. Check they are inputting a valid letter not multiple letters or a number.
3. What happens if it's a word such as 'Good' and they guess an 'o' at the moment my code breaks if this is the case. Also where on Earth would this be included in the code?

Here is my code

```
import random
import math
import time
import sys


def hangman():
    if guess == 5:
            print "  ----------|\n /\n|\n|\n|\n|\n|\n|\n______________"
            print
            print "Strike one, the tigers are getting lonely!"
            time.sleep(.5)
            print "You have guessed the letters- ", guessedLetters
            print  " ".join(blanks)
            print

    elif guess == 4:
        print "  ----------|\n /          O\n|\n|\n|\n|\n|\n|\n______________"
        print
        print "Strike two, pressure getting to you?"
        time.sleep(.5)
        print "You have guessed the letters- ", guessedLetters
        print  " ".join(blanks)
        print

    elif guess == 3:
        print "  ----------|\n /          O\n|         \_|_/ \n|\n|\n|\n|\n|\n______________"
        print
        print "Strike three, are you even trying?"
        time.sleep(.5)
        print "You have guessed the letters- ", guessedLetters
        print  " ".join(blanks)
        print

    elif guess == 2:
        print "  ----------|\n /          O\n|         \_|_/ \n|           |\n|\n|\n|\n|\n______________"
        print
        print "Strike four, might aswell giveup, your already half way to your doom. Oh wait, you can't give up."
        time.sleep(.5)
        print "You have guessed the letters- ", guessedLetters
        print  " ".join(blanks)
        print

    elif guess == 1:
        print "  ----------|\n /          O\n|         \_|_/ \n|           |\n|          / \\ \n|\n|\n|\n______________"
        print
        print "One more shot and your done for, though I knew this would happen from the start"
        time.sleep(.5)
        print "You have guessed the letters- ", guessedLetters
        print  " ".join(blanks)
        print

elif guess == 0:
        print "  ----------|\n /          O\n|         \_|_/ \n|           |\n|          / \\ \n|       GAME OVER!\n|\n|\n______________"

        print "haha, its funny cause you lost."
        print "p.s the word was", choice
        print


words = ["BAD","RUGBY","JUXTAPOSED","TOUGH","HYDROPNEUMATICS"]

choice = random.choice(words)


lenWord = len(choice)

guess = 6

guessedLetters = []

blanks = []

loading = ".........."

print "Loading",
for char in loading:
    time.sleep(.5)
    sys.stdout.write(char)
    sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(.5)
print "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"

print "Great I'm glad to see you have finally woken."
time.sleep(1)
raw_input("Did you have a nice journey? ")
time.sleep(2)

print """
Oh wait, I don't care.
I have brought you to this island simply for my amusment. I also get                   paid to do this.
"""

time.sleep(2)
print"""
Don't worry this isn't all for nothing.
I'm sure the tigers will enjoy your company.
"""

time.sleep(2)
print"""
Hold on, let us make things interesting.
"""

time.sleep(2)
print "I will let you live if you complete an impossible game!"
time.sleep(2)
print "A game know as hangman!"
time.sleep(2)
print "HAHAHAHAHAH, I am so evil, you will never escape!"
time.sleep(2)
print "Enjoy your stay :)"

time.sleep(1)
print
print "Alright lets begin! If you wish to guess the word type an '!' and   you will be prompted"
time.sleep(.5)
print

for s in choice:
    missing = choice.replace(choice, "_")
    blanks.append("_")
    print missing,
print
time.sleep(.5)

while guess > 0:
    letterGuess = raw_input("Please enter a letter: ")
    letterGuess = letterGuess.upper()

    if letterGuess == "!":
        print "If you guess the FULL word correcly then you win, if incorrect you die. Simple."
        fullWordGuess = raw_input("What is the FULL Word? ")
        fullWordGuess = fullWordGuess.upper()
        if fullWordGuess == choice:
            print "You must have hacked this game"
            time.sleep(.5)
            print "Looks like you beat an impossible game! \nGood Job \nI'll show myself out."
            break
        else:
            print "You lost, I won, you're dead :) Have a nice day!"
            print "P.S The word was ", choice
            break
    else:
        print

    if letterGuess in choice:
        location = choice.find(letterGuess)

        blanks.insert(location, letterGuess)
        del blanks[location+1]

        print " ".join(blanks)

        guessedLetters.append(letterGuess)
        print
        print "You have guessed the letters- ", guessedLetters

        if "_" not in blanks:
            print "Looks like you beat an impossible game! \nGood Job \nI'll show myself out."
            break
        else:
            continue

    else:

        guessedLetters.append(letterGuess)
        guess -= 1
        hangman()
```

Comment: Don't use find, iterate over the string and just replace any occurrences using str.join, that will handle multiple repeats

Comment: Cool game! Here's a couple of coding tips. (1) Duplication is usually bad, try to get rid of it. (2) Python has multiline strings if you use triple quotes. See http://pastebin.com/MVc3D03q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not really follow your code since there seems to be something wrong with your indentation, and the many print's confused me a little, but here is how I would suggest soving your Questions:

1.1. Create a list of guessed characters:

```
guessed_chars = []
if(guess in guessed_chars):
    guessed_chars.append(guess)
    #do whatever you want to do with the guess.
else:
    print("You already guessed that.")
    #do what ever you want to do if you already guessed that.
```

1.2 Lets say the word the player has to ges is `word = "snake"`. To get the indices (since a string is just a list of charcters in python, only that it is immutable) where the guessed letter is in the word you could then use something  like:

```
reveal = "_"*len(word)
temp = ""
for i, j in enumerate(word):
    if j == guess:
        temp += guess
    else:
        temp += reveal[i]

reveal = temp
print(reveal)
```

2. Maybe not fancy but it should work:

   `if (guess not in [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z]):`
3. with my suggestion for 1.2 you would just have to check `if(word==reveal):` no problem with duplicate charcters.

Since I am just a hobbyist there would probably be a more professional way though.
Next time maybe splitting up your question and first looking them up individually would be better, since I am pretty sure that at least parts of your questions have been asked before.